# Can I use a LAPL/PPL issued by the UK CAA to fly outside Europe?

Tags: ppl, caa-uk-regulations, lapl

Will the Light Aircraft Pilot License (LAPL) or Private Pilot License (PPL) be enough to to be able to fly to other countries outside Europe?

Comment: PPL(A) or LAPL(A)? Your text is a bit ambigous there...

Comment: Well, which one is better?  Is the PPL better than LAPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EASA issued LAPL(A) is limited to 2to MTOM, 3 passengers max and only valid in European countries. A PPL(A) issued by an EASA country does not have these restrictions, but can be subject to local restrictions in the non-European country you want to flyin, e.g. you cannot use the EASA PPL(A) to fly in the US without further paperwork.

For more information, see the [UK CAA's page on the LAPL](http://www.caa.co.uk/default.aspx?catid=2701&pagetype=90&pageid=15222).

> Your LAPL(A) is a lifetime licence that contains SEP(land) and/or TMG privileges restricted to non-complex EASA aeroplanes with a maximum take off mass of 2 metric tonnes and a maximum of four people on board.
>
> You can fly more complex aeroplanes within the privileges if you have 'differences training' signed off in your log book by a suitable instructor. The LAPL is also valid on non-EASA UK registered aircraft in the UK.
>
> The LAPL requires an in-date EASA Part-Med Medical Certificate, at LAPL level, but Class One or Class Two certificates can also be used. A valid JAA Class One or Two medical certificate is also acceptable. But you cannot use your LAPL with an NPPL medical declaration.
>
> The SEP(land) or TMG endorsement on this type of licence is not issued as a rating. So there is no rating expiry date. Instead you must follow self-validity checks on your own flying history for the past 2 years to ensure currency on the day of your planned flight.

Further Reading from the UK CAA:
[EASA Light Aircraft Pilot License Aeroplane - LAPL(A)](http://www.caa.co.uk/application.aspx?catid=2685&pagetype=65&appid=54&mode=summary&appprocsum=13)
[EASA Private Pilots Licence Aeroplane - PPL(A)](http://www.caa.co.uk/application.aspx?catid=2685&pagetype=65&appid=54&mode=summary&appprocsum=8)